# Sort Months into Array

Tags: javascript, sorting, date, dictionary

I have got an dict with dates and a countervalue

```
dates = {'01.02.2014':'2', '02.03.2014':'5', '10.03.2014':'9', '20.06.2014':'7'}
```

what i need are new dict's for all months in the "dates" dict.

```
Feb = {'01.02.2014':'2'};
March = {'02.03.2014':'5', '10.03.2014':'9'};
Jun = {'20.06.2014':'7'};
```

Is there a good and fast way to achieve this?

thanks a lot,

best regards

linda

Comment: What have you tried?  Stackoverflow is not a show me the code site.  We will answer questions if you have a problem.  Giving requirements and expecting code is not going to get a positive response, in general.

Comment: Are you using any library for this? JQuery or just pure JS?

Comment: i'm using only JS. I'm write with you Hogan, but sometimes you are sitting in front of a problem and thinkung about it with no result. And then it's good if someone shows you how to do that. If i unerstand the given code then it's ok...it's not only copy paste ...

Answer (score 2):

Like the others, loop over the object and construct a new one:

```
var dates = {'01.02.2014':'2', '02.03.2014':'5', '10.03.2014':'9', '20.06.2014':'7'}
var months = {'01':'Jan','02':'Feb','03':'Mar','04':'Apr','05':'May','06':'Jun',
              '07':'Jul','08':'Aug','09':'Sep','10':'Oct','11':'Nov','12':'Dec'};
var dates2 = {};

// Requires ES5
Object.keys(dates).forEach(function(key) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[key] = dates[key];
  dates2[months[key.split('.')[1]]] = obj;
})

console.log(dates2);
```

or for greater compatibility (and probably speed) you can use a plain for..in loop:

```
for (var key in dates) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[key] = dates[key];
  dates2[months[key.split('.')[1]]] = obj;
}
```

Comment: Does ES5 forEach guarantee execution order?

Answer (score 1):

There is no **special trick** to do this fast.  Just loop over your data structure and put the elements in another data structure.

Comment: I think this should be a comment, not answer, because this doesn't provide a solution

Comment: @hindmost - I don't agree -- it is as specific as the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dates = {'01.02.2014':'2', '02.03.2014':'5', '10.03.2014':'9'};

// Create a map to translate numbers to months 
var map = {  
    '01': 'Jan',
    '02': 'Feb',
    '03': 'Mar' // etc...
};

var ret = {};

for(var key in dates){

    var monthKey = key.split('.')[1], // Get month
        translated = map[monthKey], // Translate to text
        kvp = {};

    kvp[key] = dates[key];

    if(!ret[translated]) // Add new month prop if not exist
        ret[translated] = kvp;
    else // Add prop to existing month
        ret[translated][key] = dates[key];  
}

console.log(ret);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xpm5enrj/